# Run-time error when trying to run a recorded macro with chart repositioning

Tags: excel, vba, charts

When I try to run a recorded macro with chart repositioning (code below),

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$4")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 185
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -35.5
End Sub
```

I get a run-time error (picture below)

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1")` ... Avoid referring to the shape by name.

---

[`Shapes.AddChart2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.addchart2) has optional `Top` and `Left` parameters (sample values below, may need tweaked), and also returns a `Shape` object that you can use further.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim chartShape As Shape
    Set chartShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlBarClustered, 467.25, 3.25)

    Dim dataCells As Range
    Set dataCells = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B4")

    chartShape.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=dataCells
End Sub
```

<sup>* Depending on your setup, it might be better to use the sheet name (e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`), or codename (e.g. `Sheet1`), rather than `ActiveSheet`.</sup>